# Print in LCD I2C arduino by using matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino, display, i2c, lcd

I get tired to find how to run this code written in arduino using matlab the code will print a message into LCD I2C it work fine in arduino but in matlab is there a way to run this code in matlab or load the arduino code in matlab and run...

```
//load libraries
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LCD.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

//Define variables 

#define I2C_ADDR          0x3F        //Define I2C Address where the PCF8574A is
#define BACKLIGHT_PIN      3
#define En_pin             2
#define Rw_pin             1
#define Rs_pin             0
#define D4_pin             4
#define D5_pin             5
#define D6_pin             6
#define D7_pin             7

//Initialise the LCD
LiquidCrystal_I2C      lcd(I2C_ADDR, En_pin,Rw_pin,Rs_pin,D4_pin,D5_pin,D6_pin,D7_pin);

void setup()
 {
    //Define the LCD as 16 column by 2 rows 
    lcd.begin (16,2);

    //Switch on the backlight
    lcd.setBacklightPin(BACKLIGHT_PIN,POSITIVE);
    lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);

    //goto first column (column 0) and first line (Line 0)
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);

    //Print at cursor Location
    lcd.print("Finally!");

    //goto first column (column 0) and second line (line 1)
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Work :)");

 }


void loop(){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Develop in the Arduino IDE all of the programs/sketches that you will need
2. In the Arduino IDE, turn ON verbose output via File -> Preferences
3. Upload program to Arduino (for example the one you have pasted here).
4. When upload is finished, record the last line of the compilation output. If my program is called blink1, then I saved this line to blink1_cmd.txt

   [image: reference image]

   notice in the refernce picture the last line is:

   ```
   C:\ArduinoIDE\hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\ArduinoIDE\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P\\.\COM9 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\PAULJO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build6145494704296263461.tmp\blink1.cpp.hex:i
   ```
5. Find the HEX file associated with your program and save it elsewhere. in the case above:

   ```
   C:\Users\PAULJO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build6145494704296263461.tmp\blink1.cpp.hex
   ```

   And I moved it to:

   ```
   C:\Users\PAULJO~1\Documents\MATLAB\TestCode\Arduino\ArduinoIdeProgramming\blink1.cpp.hex
   ```
6. In your text file, update the HEX file path.
7. Copy the entire line from the text file.
8. In the Matlab command window:

   ```
   [status,cmdout] = dos(' paste code here ')
   ```

   You should get an output of:

   ```
   avrdude done. Thank you.
   ```
9. Repeat as necessary for the other programs.